# How do I store temporary data manipulated by my ASP.NET module?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, digest-authentication

I estimate implementing [WSSE authentication](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html) by extending code similar to [this custom authentication module](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/).

That code will be hosted in ASP.NET and registered in `<system.web><httpModules>` section in web.config file of the site. An instance of the module will be created by some code inside IIS, passed the request, live for some time and then destroyed.

In order to implement WSSE I need to somehow keep track of issued challenges ("nonces") to be able to prevent replay attacks.

So I need to store recent challenges somewhere in such way that the collection will persist between incoming requests and will be accessible by all the module instances.

What is the most convenient (in terms of using it from C# and deploying it on a new server) and most typical solution for that?

Comment: Application.Cache is a shared space in the application context, could do the job

Answer (score 0):

Session["mySess"] can also help you